# Book read/published in the mid/late 90's about a virus embedded in an OS update by an evil MS like organisation

Tags: story-identification, novel

Overview - Short novel, believed to be self published. Read mid/late 90's in document form, not bound.

#### Characters:

- IT Ops guy working at a company notices a problem with the updates / actions of the OS causing virus.
- Evil IT Corporation leader - runs worldwide (MS like) IT org that plans to and delivers virus/malware across worlds computers grabbing money/shutting down systems.
- ? Detective looking into the crime? May be from a similar book!

#### Plot:

IT guy at company notices a malware/virus. Evil MS like org leader infects all worldwide OS via an update and shuts down/steals systems for profit.

Comment: I hate to ask, but any fantasy/sci-fi aspects? This all sounds pretty real-world even if the events haven't happened like that yet. [No Biblical apocalypse plot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/232930/23243)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not science fiction or fantasy